# An issue on iPhones where performing a specific action while scrolling a certain element causes the interior of that element to appear white

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, scroll

## Describe

There is an issue observed on iPhones. When scrolling during an active scrolling attempt, pressing the "scroll to top" button causes the content within the scrolling element to disappear temporarily. This issue occurs regardless of the browser used, such as Chrome or Safari. This phenomenon occurs on iPhone X and iPhone Mini 13.

However, if the scrolling has come to a stop before pressing the "scroll to top" button, this problem doesn't occur.

the steps in GIF Image are as follows:

1. An attempt to scroll the list element.
2. Pressing the "scroll to top" button while the scrolling is ongoing.
3. Confirming the appearance of a white screen.
4. Upon attempting to scroll again, the top elements gradually reappear, and the scrolling functions as expected.

## GIF Image

[image]

## Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            height: 100vh;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        
        .test-list {
            width: 100%;
            height: 220px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="scroll-to-top">scroll to top</button>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="test-list">1</div>
        <div class="test-list">2</div>
        <div class="test-list">3</div>
        <div class="test-list">4</div>
        <div class="test-list">5</div>
        <div class="test-list">6</div>
        <div class="test-list">7</div>
        <div class="test-list">8</div>
        <div class="test-list">9</div>
        <div class="test-list">10</div>
        <div class="test-list">11</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        const $button = document.querySelector('.scroll-to-top')
        const $container = document.querySelector('.container')
        $button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            $container.scrollTo({ top: 0 })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```